# TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'yfinance.ticker.Options'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, yfinance

Below is my code to pull stock option data from a list of stock tickers then concatenate all of the stock option's dataframes into one. However, I am getting the following error message: "TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'yfinance.ticker.Options'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"

```
opt_appended = []

for symbol in tickers:
    try:
        ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
        opt = ticker.option_chain('2021-07-30')
        opt_appended.append(opt)
    except ValueError:
        continue
opt_appended = pd.concat(opt_appended)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequential appends to a DataFrame are extremely costly as it requires a new DataFrame to be build every iteration. For this reason, they are generally avoided. Since  `option_chain` returns an iterable, instead of appending to the list we should `extend` the list. Then perform a single [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) at the end.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL', 'AA', 'AAL']

opts_list = []

for symbol in tickers:
    try:
        ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
        opt = ticker.option_chain('2021-07-30')
        opts_list.extend(opt)
    except ValueError:
        continue

new_df = pd.concat(opts_list)
```

`new_df`:

```
         contractSymbol       lastTradeDate  ...  contractSize  currency
0   AAPL210730C00065000 2021-07-28 19:37:45  ...       REGULAR       USD
1   AAPL210730C00070000 2021-07-22 18:17:27  ...       REGULAR       USD
2   AAPL210730C00075000 2021-07-28 17:19:38  ...       REGULAR       USD
3   AAPL210730C00080000 2021-07-22 14:59:05  ...       REGULAR       USD
4   AAPL210730C00085000 2021-07-27 16:09:57  ...       REGULAR       USD
..                  ...                 ...  ...           ...       ...
28   AAL210730P00029000 2021-07-26 13:31:18  ...       REGULAR       USD
29   AAL210730P00029500 2021-07-26 13:32:22  ...       REGULAR       USD
30   AAL210730P00030000 2021-07-22 16:52:08  ...       REGULAR       USD
31   AAL210730P00031000 2021-07-22 15:53:55  ...       REGULAR       USD
32   AAL210730P00032000 2021-07-26 13:30:11  ...       REGULAR       USD

[253 rows x 14 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to bind to a list, we can't use pd.concat(), so if we make the initial value a data frame, the problem is solved.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

tickers = ['AAPL','AA','AAL']

opt_appended = pd.DataFrame()

for symbol in tickers:
    try:
        ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
        opt = ticker.option_chain('2021-07-30')
        opt_appended = opt_appended.append(opt)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

|  | contractSymbol | lastTradeDate | strike | lastPrice | bid | ask | change | percentChange | volume | openInterest | impliedVolatility | inTheMoney | contractSize | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAPL210730C00065000 | 2021-07-28 19:37:45 | 65 | 80.32 | 78.75 | 81.3 | -1.18 | -1.44785 | 5 | 81 | 4.1875 | True | REGULAR | USD |
| 1 | AAPL210730C00070000 | 2021-07-22 18:17:27 | 70 | 74.95 | 74.3 | 75.8 | -2.26 | -2.92708 | 2 | 153 | 4.01563 | True | REGULAR | USD |
| 2 | AAPL210730C00075000 | 2021-07-28 17:19:38 | 75 | 70.05 | 69.25 | 70.85 | -3.39999 | -4.62899 | 20 | 197 | 3.67188 | True | REGULAR | USD |
| 3 | AAPL210730C00080000 | 2021-07-22 14:59:05 | 80 | 67.8 | 63.9 | 66.25 | 0 | 0 | 67 | 133 | 3.46094 | True | REGULAR | USD |
| 4 | AAPL210730C00085000 | 2021-07-27 16:09:57 | 85 | 60.95 | 59.6 | 61.15 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 186 | 3.89063 | True | REGULAR | USD |

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: It's odd- your answer worked perfectly when I tried it last night, but it did not this morning, I got an error, so I am accepting the other answer as the correct answer as that one is working